# Can there be multiples of the same CHOICE field in a rfc5280 certificate?

Tags: certificate, rfc

I'm currently validating my implementation of a certificate conforming to the [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280).

The General Name is defined as:

```
GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
    otherName     [0] OtherName,
    rfc822Name    [1] IA5String,
    dNSName       [2] IA5String,
    x400Address   [3] ORAddress,
    directoryName [4] Name,
    ediPartyName  [5] EDIPartyName,
    uniformResourceIdentifier [6] IA5String,
    iPAddress     [7] OCTET STRING,
    registeredID  [8] OBJECT IDENTIFIER }
```

Now I can't find the definition of the `CHOICE` keyword. Is it possible for my certificate to contain multiple directoryName-, or URI-fields? Or does choice mean any of the below but not more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for my certificate to contain multiple directoryName-, or URI-fields?

Yes.

> Or does choice mean any of the below but not more than once?

Also yes.

---

A choice is a single choice.  It probably says it succinctly in the document somewhere, but [ITU-T X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-201508-I/en) always refers to choices as single values, such as:

> 29.8 The choice type contains values which do not all have the same tag. (The tag depends on ***the alternative*** which contributed ***the value*** to the choice type.)
>
> <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

The certificate can contain multiple directoryName/etc values because things like the subject alternative name extension don't have `GeneralName` values, they have `GeneralNames` values.  And, of course, `GeneralNames ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF GeneralName`